# curl 'SSL connect error'

Tags: tls, curl

basic steps taken:

```
# echo -n | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/example.cert
# curl -v --cacert /tmp/example.cert https://example.com/
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 123.45.67.89... connected
* Connected to example.com (123.45.67.89) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: example.cert
  CApath: none
* NSS error -12188
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

I tried pem with a certificate chain, and also as just the plain host certificate.

Sometimes I also get the error `Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)`.

also tried (as a temporary work around):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

# echo 'insecure' > $CURL_HOME/.curlrc
```

still I will end up with `SSL connect error`.

Comment: like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887315/curl-ssl-connect-error-35-with-nss-error-5961

Comment: @schroeder if you mean `--cacert` then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use curl.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => http_build_query(array([...])),
    'protocol_version' => 1.1,
    'timeout' => 10,
    'ignore_errors' => true
  )
));
$result = file_get_contents('https://example.com/', false, $context);
```

`stream_context_create` works just as well.