# The SSL CA cert (path? access rights) on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate

Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?).  I got a SSL cert from Commodo and it installed ok.  Everything seems to be working correctly and I have restarted my server and Apache2.

`Service apache2 status` shows no errors.

This was used:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -fy && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -fy
```

The issues I see online either deal with Amazons Linux (using yum) or CentOS.  They said to restart the server.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and not sure what to do next?

This affects packages being downloaded such as this example:

I tried to do a command such as:

I made a composer.json file

```
{
  "require": {
      "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.*"
  }
}
```

composer install

```
[RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.php.git via https, ssh
   protocols, aborting.
  - https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.php.git
    Cloning into '/var/www/ssl/s3/test/vendor/mtdowling/jmespath.php'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.php.git/':
  Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
  - git@github.com:jmespath/jmespath.php.git
    Cloning into '/var/www/ssl/s3/test/vendor/mtdowling/jmespath.php'...
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the `git clone` SSL error on a small Debian distro ([Voyage Linux](http://linux.voyage.hk/)), and it was because the standard root CAs weren't installed, meaning that git (and even simple things like `curl https://google.com`) couldn't verify the SSL certificates of HTTPS sites.

The solution at [lxadm](https://lxadm.com/Git_clone:_Problem_with_the_SSL_CA_cert), which worked for me, was just to install `ca-certificates`:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
```

Comment: This was installed for me (18.04) and still got error but doing a `sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates` fixed it.   Not sure why this was downvoted but I upvoted back to zero as it solved my issue.  (imho downvote without comment or upvoting existing comment shouldn't be allowed)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion  SSH key is not authorized in this scenario and you need to create public SSH key and ask the admin of Git repository to add SSH public key. You can refer below URL for more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430311/saving-ssh-key-fails/8600087#8600087

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Installing a root/CA Certificate.
Given a CA certificate file foo.crt, follow these steps to install it on Ubuntu:

Create a directory for extra CA certificates in /usr/share/ca-certificates:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra
```

Copy the CA .crt file to this directory:

```
sudo cp foo.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/foo.crt
```

Let Ubuntu add the .crt file's path relative to /usr/share/ca-certificates to /etc/ca-certificates.conf:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 0):

We were seeing intermittent failures of `git clone` commands in the provisioning scripts for an elastic beanstalk Ubuntu 16 instance. If the errors are occurring when a new server instance has just been started, it's possible that `unattended-upgrades` is running on boot as a result of `apt.daily`
as discussed in [this other thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315502/how-to-disable-apt-daily-service-on-ubuntu-cloud-vm-image), and happens to be upgrading `ca-certificates` at the time the provisioning scripts are running.

We baked a new image with the latest security updates installed as a first step, which solved the intermittent failures, and to prevent the problem recurring followed the solution from [here](https://github.com/geerlingguy/packer-boxes/issues/3#issuecomment-219257091), which was to add the file

`/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer.d/apt-daily.timer.conf`

```
[Timer]
Persistent=false
```

The `persistent` setting is there "to catch up on missed runs of the service when the system was powered down" according to the [systemd.timer man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.timer.5.html), so setting it to false prevents the daily tasks, including `unattended-upgrades`, from running on boot.